# Why does Swagger show "422 Validation Error" under the responses section of my docs?

Tags: swagger, fastapi

I'm building a REST API with Python's [fastapi](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/). One benefit of fastapi is that it automatically generates API docs using [Swagger](https://swagger.io/).

Here I've define a dummy `delete()` path operation.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, status

app = FastAPI()

@app.delete('/blog/{id}', status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
def delete_blog(id: int):
    return "test"
```

When I visit the auto-generated swagger docs (http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs), my delete endpoint shows 422 Validation Error under *Responses*.

[image]

Where does this come from? Why don't see 422 Validation error when I create a `get()` path operation? And why don't I see other possible Responses like 500?

Comment: It's an example of what a 422 error would look like. A 500 internal server error isn't a possibility from _the route definition_ itself.

Comment: Also, you may enter an url like `blog/aaaa` which is not valid, since you defined it as type `int` and not `str`

Comment: @Isabi thanks, I think I understand now. Because I used a parameter type hint (i.e. `id: int`) there's the possibility that the server will return a 422 Validation Error if the user requests a non integer blog id like `/blog/aaaa`. Had I left out the type hint, the 422 Validation Error would not appear in the docs.